# C#: using Python.Runtime not found

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I tried to embedded a python script using Python for .NET. And in the C# program, I tried to import the class

```
using Python.RunTime;
```

but it cannot be found. I cannot find out the reason for that. I have already installed pythonnet in my python interpreter.

I just want to test it out by codes like:

```
using (Py.GIL)
{
  dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
  MessageBox.Show(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

I have add reference Python.Runtime.dll in the VS project. And when execute, it got System.BadImageFormatException. I have no clue why that happened.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the python.net Dll?

Comment: Yes. I added the reference Python.Runtime.dll at the visual studio. However, when execute the code, it has System.BadImageFormatException.

Since the code can be compiled, and the Visual Studio also found the dll, I think there is no problem on adding the references. But i cannot understand why there is such exception.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this answer help others who encountered similar problem.

1. Add the dll as a reference at the VS. It should be located at locations like "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Python.Runtime.dll." if you have done installation of pythonnet via pip.
2. System.BadImageFormatException is due to the problem that I set the project to ANY platform, but the python interpreter is 64 bit. Need to change the target platform to match the interpreter.